# Website - one session for everyone in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first post on stackoverflow. I've been learning javascript for 1 week already, done couple of things I'm proud of, but right now I don't know where to look for the solution. I'm a self-learner, so please dont judge.

I'm doing a website board game with javascript and I'm pretty progressing with that, but I think I'm stuck. I want to make it kinda multiplayerish, people enter the website and make changes/moves so other people see it.

What do I have to know and dive into to solve this problem on my website?

Thanks!

Comment: It won't actually be one session for everyone.  It will just be a single "room" for everyone.  You'll still need session for each player.  If you really want to dive in head first, look into something like [socket.IO](https://socket.io/).  You can't do any of this without a server and that's a whole other can of worms beyond just front-end coding.

Answer (score 1):

Since Javascript is basically a "Client side", then i'm not sure it it possible without server side. There must be a data base which is managed on server side for sure (in order to store all the different players), and while you at it, assign a unique id via that same server side language (for example, php) and then you can always print that id to a javascript file.

Comment: That's actually what I thought, that there's no way without implementing server-side part to this. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, since javascript in a webpage is client-side you can't achieve this. If you are making a multiplayer game one good approach could be using websockets or maybe polling of http requests. If you are familiarized with javascript you could try to look up for Node.js that let's you create backends with javascript or, maybe you could use the backend language of your preference (PHP, Java, C#, Python, etc..) to build a server for your game.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you very much! will do that for sure! ;)